# Perl Net::Telnet::Cisco cmd not returning response for Dell servers

Tags: perl

I post a question a week ago but I really did not get anywhere with is so I have changed modules that I am using and I believe I am getting further. The following code is basically trying to get information from Cisco and Dell servers.

```
$swConn = Net::SSH2::Cisco->new(Host => "$switchname.something", Prompt =>  

'/' . $switch .'#/') or push(@skipFailedSwitches, $switch);

##############################################################################
# Changes for Cisco Nexus 5020 Switch start here
#
# Included the code for varying the password depending on switch
##############################################################################


    $password = #mypassword;


  print "logging into $switchname.something  with username $username and password $password \n"; #SBW

  if (not $swConn->login($username, $password)){
    push(@skipFailedSwitches, $switch);
    next;
  }
  #$swConn->login(Password => #mypassword);
#$fh = $swConn->input_log();

$swConn->cmd('terminal length 0') or push(@skipFailedSwitches, $switch);
print my @statusOut = $swConn->cmd('show interface status') or push(@skipFailedSwitches, $switch);
```

My issue is that with Cisco, the print statement at the end returns what the server console returns, while the Dell just returns what I sent it (i.e. "some information that I need" versus "show interface status"). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A frozen shaking me overcomes still. You may fail, because a missing chomp() to dispatch from the false linebreak in a double.

I'll not expect, that sidepass coders understand, what i said. It's a shame, that through these years, just sometimes leaved qualified code.

And when i see, what kind of understatements arounds, there is no hope for pricipal riders.

Comment: In trying that I still got a ton of information from the Cisco switch but the Dell still returns "show interface status" as the return.